# Spring cloud stream - Local Consumer intercepts message and blocking others

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to base applications messaging on `spring cloud stream` relying on `RabbitMQ` binder.
I have a general message\event. Some applications might be the source of such message and some of them are also consumers of such a message.
Each of the applications do different logic with that message data.
For instance, `Application A`:

```java
 @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<MyMessage>> onMyMessage() {
        return msg -> {
            // Get the contained message, log and return it
            MyActualMessage myActualMessage = msg.getPayload();
            log.debug("Received Cloud Event with some important data as POJO: " + myActualMessage toString());

            // Handle manual approval request has been decided
            if (myActualMessage.getOperationData() == OperationData.Charge) {
                // Do some logic related to this micro service...
            }
        };
    }
```

But `Application A` can also produce such an event:

```java
public void sendDirectMessage(MyActualMessage message) {

        try {
            // Wrap the message in CloudEvent spec message
            Message<String> inputMessage = CloudEventMessageBuilder
                    .withData(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message))
                    .setSource("https://spring.io/spring-event")
                    .setType("com.example.springevent")
                    .build();

            this.streamBridge.send("onMyMessage-in-0", inputMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new MyMessagingException(String.format("Failed to send a a message: %s", message.toString()), ex);
        }
    }
```

And the same goes for other applications as well.
**When I send a message I expect it to reach all of the consumers but it only goes to the local consumer**... (The local consumer can ignore it by checking a sender field, it's not a problem if it will not get filtered).
I tried to give for every application different consumer-group name (Maybe my definition is wrong?) to no avail...

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: onMyMessage
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: ApplicationA
```

(The group name is different for every application).
**Any idea what can be the problem and how can I overcome it?**

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a mess with the binding names as for the producer as for the consumer.

First take a look to the binding name conventions at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names

> input - <functionName> + -in- + <index> 
> output - <functionName> + -out- + <index>

Having said that. You should call to the streamBridge as follows:

```
this.streamBridge.send("onMyMessage-out-0", inputMessage);
```

And your bindings configuration should be something like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: onMyMessage
    stream:
      bindings:
        onMyMessage-out-0:
          destination: my-topic
        onMyMessage-in-0:
          destination: my-topic
          group: ApplicationA
```